# Imageview not scaling picture

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have the following imageview with a image smaller than the RelativeLayout that contains this ImageView. I want the image scalled to fit the width of the imageView but I cannot make this works. For example I 
have this relativeLayout with **350dp width**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_button_grey"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_selector"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:src="@drawable/Nachos"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/image_selector_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_selector"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"

        android:textSize="18sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see in the picture the image is in the center. The problem with fitXY is that the width works, but doesn't change the height. I want somehitng like, **fitX**. I have also tried **centerInside** but it looks the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used another method. First, I obtaing the dimesions without loading from memory :

```
   BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                try {
                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, bitmapOptions);
                    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getName(), bitmapOptions);
                    float scale = (bitmapOptions.outHeight * 1f) / (bitmapOptions.outWidth);
                    cache.put(image, value);
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Then used that value **scale**

```
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(IMAGE_SIZE, Math.round(IMAGE_SIZE * imageData.getScale())));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.setCropToPadding(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would also use `centerCrop`or similar. If that does not work for you, check this image and see if you can find anything interesting: 
[image]

If this is nothing for you, consider to check out image customazations in Android:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Answer (score 1):

Because your Relative layout and Imageview both have wrap content height so you have to make them match parent and make scaletype fitXY..

as follow code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_button_grey"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="5dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_selector"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:src="@drawable/Nachos"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/image_selector_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image_selector"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `android:scaleType` attribute to your ImageView.

If you want to display the pictures in proportion, you can use `centerCrop`.

If you don't want to display the pictures in proportion, you can use `fitXY`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button_grey"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_selector"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/Nachos" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/image_selector_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_selector"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But centerCrop will crop the image. I want the image bigger, to fit in the WIDTH of the relative layout.

Comment: If you use your width and height completely, you need use `fitXY` or `centerCrop` .

Comment: `centerCrop`is also scaled

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!
In my case it is working fine.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/Nachos">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some padding set on the `RelativeLayout` they may be also a cause to `ImageView` not touching the sides in your layout `RelativeLayout`:

Remove this:

```
android:padding="5dp"
```

And if you real want some padding set on Top and Bottom but **NOT** on the Right and Left so if you want padding Top and Bottom **ADD** these:

```
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
```

And if you do not want padding at all do not **ADD** them!